# Strange behavior of MATCH function

Tags: excel, excel-2010, excel-match

In Excel 2010, Windows 7, I encounter following strange behavior of `MATCH` function.

In `A1`, type in `0.81`, and select `A1:B1`, click <kbd>Fill->Series</kbd>, in `step value` box enter `0.01`, then we have `0.82` in `B1`.

In `A2`, type in `0.82`, and in `B2`, enter formula:

```
=MATCH(A2,A1:B1,0)
```

Then we would have `#N/A` error, the whole thing looks like this:

```
0.81    0.82
0.82    #N/A
```

But when I hand-type `0.82` in `B1`, everything works fine, is it a bug or these two number are different in some sense? I tried

```
TYPE(B1)=TYPE(A2) and B1=A2
```

They both return `TRUE`, what formula can show that they are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Great question**

This is a matter of precision...........even though **B1** appears to be an exact match to **A2,** it is not.  There are close, VERY close; so close that even *=A2=B1* will return *True.*

But they are not close enough to **MATCH()** to work.

**EDIT#1:**

To examine the difference between **B1** and **A2** run this VBA macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim A2 As Range, B1 As Range
    Set A2 = Range("A2")
    Set B1 = Range("B1")
    v1 = A2.Value
    v2 = B1.Value
    MsgBox (v1 = v2) & vbCrLf & v1 - v2
End Sub
```

You should see:

-1.11022302462516E-16

Without VBA, the **=DELTA()** function will also reveal them to be un-equal.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice this might be the reason. But if I change the number to 0.82 and 0.83, it works fine again, so the difference of error tolerance between "=" and MATCH() should be small, where can I find such documentation?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315961 for HLOOKUP and VLOOKUP, but applies to MATCH too.